# Retutning object as result from method

Tags: java, oop, pointers, reference

I started to learn part where we return object as result from method, and i got a little bit stuck in here. And i would be grateful if anyone of you could help me. Here's the code from my book

```
class Test
{
   int a;

   Test(int i)
   {
      a=i;
   }
   Test increment()
   {
      Test privremeni = new Test(a+a);
      return privremeni;
   }
}
public class ReturnObject 
   {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
      Test ob1 = new Test(2);
      Test ob2;

      ob2 = ob1.increment();
      System.out.println("ob1.a: "+ob1.a);
      System.out.println("ob2.a: "+ob2.a);

      ob2 = ob2.increment();
      System.out.println("ob2.a after second increment(): "+ob2.a);
     }
    }
```

Confusing parts:

First: `Test ob2;` Here we don't create actual object, we only assign the reference of class Test to the object. After this object has value `null`. Right ?

Second: `ob2 = ob1.increment();` When we do this part `ob1.increment();` Then method increment() create new object called `privremeni` and return the reference of object `privremeni` and assign it to `ob2` ?

Third: `ob2 = ob2.increment()` We call again method `increment()` and it will increment again. So will `ob2` have the same reference as first time when we called `increment()` method or it will get new reference as we create new object again ?

I think i might have problem with understanding this because i still got some problems to understand part when we pass reference by value and i think that this part is really important in here.

If you could give me some more examples of this code to help me understand this i would be grateful.

Comment: `Test ob;` doesn't exist in your code, so it's hard to talk about it. If it's a local variable, it won't logically have a value until it's been assigned. If it's a field, it will have a value of null by default. Note that `ob` isn't an object in this case, it's a variable. It's important to distinguish between objects and variables (and references).

Comment: First: yes are basically right, when checking `ob2 == null` will return true. Second: You are creating a new object as the return value of the `increment()` method call, so you are correct there as well. Third: each call to `increment()` will return a new instance of Test, so the instance of `ob2` before the call is not the same as `ob2` after the call. It is a different object, not just a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First:** `Test ob2;` 
> Here we don't create actual object, we only assign the reference of class Test to the object. After this object has value null. Right ?

```
Test ob2;
```

Yes, this object is null now, but has a reference to the type of object it is, you won't be able to do `ob2 = new MyOtherTest();`.

---

> **Second:** `ob2 = ob1.increment();` 
> When we do this part `ob1.increment();` Then method `increment()` create new object called privremeni and return the reference of object privremeni and assign it to `ob2` ?

Yes, that's it! :) You will have a `Test(4)` object with `a = 4 (2+2)`

---

> **Third:** `ob2 = ob2.increment()` 
> We call again method increment() and it will increment again. So will ob2 have the same reference as first time when we called `increment()` method or it will get new reference as we create new object again ?

New object, new reference, so here `ob2 = new Test(8)`. **if you had a reference to the Test object with value 4, it will be still alive**, reading your code, `Test(4)` is now candidate for garbage collector

---

### Resuming

```
Test ob1 = new Test(2); // new object Test(2)
Test ob2;  // new memory space reserved for ob2, but ob2 = null

ob2 = ob1.increment();  // ob2 now references to Test(4) object created at increment method

// print statements

ob2 = ob2.increment(); // ob2 is now Test(8)
```

At the end of the code, assignments are:

```
ob1 = Test(2);
ob2 = Test(8);
Test(4) is elegible for garbage collector cause is not referenced.
```

---

Also look at this case where `Test(4)` is not elegible for garbage collector:

```
Test ob1 = new Test(2); // new object Test(2)
Test ob2;  // new memory space reserved for ob2, but ob2 = null

ob2 = ob1.increment();  // ob2 now references to object Test(4) created at increment method

// print statements

Test ob3 = ob2; // Test(4) is now referencing to ob2 and ob3

ob2 = ob2.increment(); // ob2 is now Test(8)
```

At the end of the code, assignments are:

```
ob1 = Test(2);
ob2 = Test(8);
ob3 = Test(4);
```

---

> I think i might have problem with understanding this because i still got some problems to understand part when we pass reference by value and i think that this part is really important in here.

```
Test ob1 = new Test(2); // new object Test(2)
Test ob2;  // new memory space reserved for ob2, but ob2 = null
ob2 = ob1.increment();  // ob2 now references to object Test(4) created 
Test ob3 = ob2; // Test(4) is now referencing to ob2 and ob3
```

If you do:

```
ob2.a = 9;  // that means also ob3.a = 9 because they reference same object!!!!
```

Comment: Part which was confusing me the most was that what happened to Test(4) at the end of the program. But now i got it, it lost it's reference after we called increment() method second time. Thanks for explanation sir. Now it is perfectly clear !

Answer (score 0):

`Test ob1 = new Test(2);` will initialize the variable aand its value will be 2

> First: Test ob; Here we don't create actual object, we only assign the
>   reference of class Test to the object. After this object has value
>   null. Right ?

I am assuming its `Test ob2`, not Test ob. 
Yes. Here we are not creating any object. But we are not assigning any reference as well. Its just a declaration. `ob2` will contain a  null value.

> Second: ob2 = ob1.increment(); When we do this part ob1.increment();
>   Then method increment() create new object called privremeni and return
>   the reference of object privremeni and assign it to ob2 ?

`ob1.increment()` will create a new object and `privremeni` which is a local variable , will refer to that object. In the next line `increment()` method is returning that object and its assigned to ob2. Instance variable `a` of `ob2` object will have a different value - 4. Because you have incremented it (2+2)

> Third: ob2 = ob2.increment() We call again method increment() and it
>   will increment again. So will ob2 have the same reference as first
>   time when we called increment() method or it will get new reference as
>   we create new object again ?

You are overwriting the value of ob2 with new object. So earlier object(mentioned in the 2nd question) will be garbage collected . And this new objecct's instance variable `a` will have a new value  8 (4+4)